# Check or Add to DB quickly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using apache, php, mysql and code igniter and I have a database set up.  In the database I have two columns that both need to be unique in combo:  latitude and longitude.

So I set up the database using this call:

```
alter table pano_raw add unique index(lat, lng)
```

Now when I insert values into the two columns (lat and lng) if the value is the same, the database should reject the write correct?

```
function addNewSet($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('sets', $data);
}
```

This function should return a true or false, depending on the success of the read or write correct?

So now how so I alter it so that when it will return the row_id of the inserted record or return FALSE?  If the write worked, I need the row_id, if it didn't I need FALSE so I can alter the code that called this function.

Would this work?  I don't think so.  Ideas?

```
function addNewSet($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('sets', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: i noticed you your sql refers to the table `pano_raw` but your CI query refers to the table `sets`. Is that a mistake? or are they 2 different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it wont return false, it will have a database error before returning false.

If you really want this, you need to go to `application/config/database.php` and change set this to false `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`

Then you should be able to do this (assuming your table has an id field set to auto increment)

```
 function addNewSet($data) {
     if ($this->db->insert('sets', $data)) {
          return $this->db->insert_id(); 
     } else {
          return FALSE;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addNewSet($data)
{
    $result = $this->db->insert('sets', $data);
    if ( $result )
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->affected_rows();` after inserting the data to check if any record was added (or affected).

So

```
function addNewSet($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('sets', $data);

    if($this->db->affected_rows()==1)
    {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // nothing was added!
    }
}
```

Should do it (untested).